# How to replace Div -content in a certain Class with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script> 
        $("div.block").each(index){
            this.text('Fill this writing of divs with the classname "block"')} 
</script>

<body>
        <div>Not here</div> 
        <div class='block'>replace me -- not working, why?</div> 
        <div>Not here</div> 
        <div class='block'>replace me -- not working, why?</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use each - you can just call the text method on your entire selection:

```
$("div.block").text('Fill this writing of divs with the classname "block"');
```

Incidentally, your problem above was that you were using [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) incorrectly

```
$("div.block").each(function(index, el){
    $(el).text('Fill this writing of divs with the classname "block"');
});
```

Comment: Those dom elements are not ready when the script runs.  You need to wrap that script in a document.ready handler, OR move the script to the very end of you body.

Comment: ...suppose I would like to fill the div with many of this kind of things `<table><td><img src='happy.png'></td><td>I am happy</td></table>` so array `values={{'happy.png','I am happy'}, {'happy2.png', 'I am also happy'}, {'hello.png', 'It is hello'}}`. How would you iterate it?

Comment: @hhh - I'm afraid I don't follow.  I'd recommend you write up a new question and fully explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes Sir, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521639/images-and-text-from-array-into-divs-with-jquery).