# Images and Text from Array into Divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

It returns `/dev/null`, why? I try to populate new divs with an image and some text.

```
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id='pitch'></div>
</body>
<script>
var v= new Array();
v[0] = new Array('h.png','Happy1!');
v[1] = new Array('hh.png','Happyy2!');
v[2] = new Array('hhh.png','Happyyy3!');

$(v).each(function(index,el){
        $(div.pitch).append("<div><img src='"+el[0]+"'>"+el[1]+"</div>");
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: ...I doubt the part `$(v)` to be nothing, how can I check it? A bit stupid question because I could ask it also as `How can I loop over an array in jQuery?`, the answer is each, more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript), but cannot get it working...

Comment: Your second script block should be inside the body of the document. If it's not in the head or body it's not valid.
You're also using div.pitch which refers to an object called div with a property called pitch (which isn't defined). Did you mean to select by id i.e. `$("#pitch").append...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the selector quotes '' and id hash

```
$('div#pitch').append("<div><img src='"+el[0]+"'>"+el[1]+"</div>");
```

Comment: You solved it, thank you! I used `'div.pitch'` though. What is the difference between dot and hash?